# How to get certificate for local network

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am developing web app using Spring Boot and React. I want to deploy it on local server and make it accessible only through local network, but I want to make it secure, so I need SSL certificate to enable HTTPS. If I use self-signed certificate then I get error on clients browsers (not secure), because this certificate is not in their trust store. Is there any way to get certificate for localhost, I think that Let's Encrypt don't give certificates for localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Generate Self signed root CA certificate.
Install your root CA in all client machines (enterprises root)
sign certificate with your root ca and install in web server

this certificate will be trusted.

Comment: Thanks for aswer, but this is not a option. I did not write in my question, but I do not have tha same clients every time.. And I do not have access to their machines.